# Python multiplication error

Tags: python

I making a program in which a single line of input containing an integer, print a triangle of asterisks of that size. But my program is not working like this. So can you please have a look on my code and can determine my mistake please. Thanks

```
line = int(raw_input("Number of lines: "))
a = line * '*'
print a
```

This is the output I want to produce:

```
Number of lines: 5
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: We aren't going through a list of homework questions, are we...? (Evidence: look at question history.)

Comment: Well its not a homework nor I'm school student I'm new to python so I'm trying to work out different question to increase my knowledge.!

Comment: @jaddy123 don't you think you need a loop around your print?

Comment: Great- let's try to discuss it then, since that will be a much better way to learn than just seeing other peoples' answers to these problems. What do you think each line of your code is supposed to do? That will help us explain where you went wrong.

Comment: SO should be a last resort after your own personal research.  It's good that your learning python, but 'give me teh codez' questions are not received well here.

Comment: alright @Matthew Adams thanks for that. well in the first as raw_input I meant that if the user inputs 5 so the output should be the triangle shaped asterisks.

Comment: You thought that the asterisks would come from `line = int(raw_input("Number of lines: "))`?

Comment: I have to say I disagree with the close votes, can't see _how_ this question falls under the description of "not a real question - ambigous, vague, incomplete, too broad or rhetorical" - it's none of those things. This is also definitely _not_ a "give me teh codez" question, OP has _written_ code and wants to know why it's not working. SO was always meant to be for all skill levels, yet people seem to think that newbies should be shut down. It's unfortunate in my opinion but, of course, I'm only one cell in the swarm, so there's not much I can do about it other than make my opinion known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is self-education rather than actual classwork, it's best explained with code and a detailed explanation of what you were doing wrong.

You're mostly there, in that you have the input and the means by which you can output a certain number of asterisks. Your problem is that you're only printing *one* line with the *maximum* number of asterisks.

You need to loop from 1 *up to that number,* each time outputting that same kind of line with an increasing length, something like:

```
line = int (raw_input ("Number of lines: "))
for i in range (1, line + 1):
    print i * '*'
```

With this code (entering 5), you basically loop with the variable `i` containing in sequence `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` (`range` is inclusive at the low end and exclusive at the high end, hence the `line + 1`).

Within that loop, you output that number of asterisks, giving you your triangle shape:

```
pax> python testprog.py
Number of lines: 5
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing it to learn Python, I will add the following:

The loop is easy to figure out, but what most people forget about is to make sure you've got the correct input from the user!

You asked the user for a number. right? 
what will happen if the user will reply with pressing the latter 'a'?